# Play music from a Bash script running from 'udev'

Tags: linux, udev

I have a [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rule to catch a USB connecting event:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[c-z]" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usbinsert.sh"
```

And Bash script (*/usr/local/bin/usbinsert.sh*):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "PASSED" >> /home/dudosyka/test.txt
mpg123 /home/dudosyka/some.mp3 alsa
exit 0
```

So, my problem: when udev runs the Bash script, it prints "PASSED" to the file without playing any song. But if I make:

```
/usr/local/bin/usbinsert.sh
```

It starts the music and prints the text.

Comment: This depends on details of your specific Linux distro and how its sound subsystem is set up; it's not a generic bash question. (bash doesn't have any sound-related functionality built-in at all!)

Comment: That said, what I'd suggest is storing mpg123's stderr to your file so you can see any error messages it write. Make your first line `exec >>/home/dudosyka/test.txt 2>&1`, and then the other lines in your script will write to that named location -- so you should see any error message mpg123 generates.

Comment: @charles-duffy Sorry for the wrong tag. I followed your advice and got the following errors:

[src / libout123 / modules / sdl.c: 122] error: Couldn't open SDL audio: No available audio device

main: [src / mpg123.c: 323] error: out123 error 7: failed to open device

Comment: SDL has several different backends available. Speaking to that error message requires which sound subsystem your Linux distro uses, and thus which backend is _required_, and also which backend(s) your copy of SSL is compiled to be able to use. From there, I'd also look into the environment variables available to select other alternative SDL sound backends, and whether your distro is compatible with any of them.

Comment: But point being, most of the problem _and its potential solutions_ aren't about bash, or about Linux in general, but about the specific Linux distro you use -- which audio server(s) it bundles, which backends it compiles SDL and associated libraries with, the specific configuration of its SDL package, etc. If you were using Ubuntu, then, I'd go bring this question to our sister site [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/); or if you were using Arch I'd start by searching the Arch wiki; etc.

Comment: Thanks and the last question, when I run the script not from udev, but directly from the console, I didn`t get any errors with music playback, why can this happen?